How do I diagnose a 38s planning time for `select *` in Postgres?
I have a table that Postgres is really struggling with planning queries on. I've been running:
explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select * from lead

The resulting query plan (literally a seq scan) is taking 36 seconds to generate. This isn't happening for any other tables, and it's not happening in our other environments (only prod). The output of explain:
Seq Scan on public.lead  (cost=0.00..63.08 rows=208 width=1550) (actual time=1.455..5.881 rows=208 loops=1)
  Output: ...columns...
  Buffers: shared read=61
Query Identifier: -594205834999675794
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=285790 read=52222 written=4
Planning Time: 38160.641 ms
Execution Time: 39.051 ms

I've tried:

vacuum (analyze, full)
analyze on the table and all tables it depends on
reindex table
Removing constraints
Removing indices

If I create a clone of the table and run on that, everything is fine, even after re-adding all constraints. pg_locks returns nothing.
All our settings are (as far as I'm aware, having never altered them) the defaults for a t4g.micro Supabase instance (2 CPU, 1GB RAM):



Setting
Value




work_mem
3500kB


maintenance_work_mem
64MB


shared_buffers
256MB



Even an index-only scan on lead.id takes 4s to plan. What am I doing wrong?

Table definition:
create table
  public.lead (
    id bigint generated always as identity,
    created_at timestamp without time zone not null default now(),
    created_by uuid null,
    deleted_at timestamp without time zone null,
    reference_code text null,
    first_name text null,
    last_name text null,
    prospect_id bigint not null,
    listing_id bigint not null,
    source text not null,
    enquiry_text text null,
    phone_number text null,
    mobile_phone_number text null,
    email_contact_permission boolean not null default false,
    phone_contact_permission boolean not null default false,
    postal_contact_permission boolean not null default false,
    home_location text null,
    work_location text null,
    current_housing_status public.current_housing_status null,
    number_of_people_in_household integer null,
    has_dependents boolean null,
    date_of_birth date null,
    key_worker_role text null,
    wheelchair_access_required boolean null,
    annual_household_income bigint null,
    cash_deposit bigint null,
    source_id bigint null,
    raw_data jsonb null,
    constraint lead_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint lead_source_source_id_unique unique (source, source_id),
    constraint lead_created_by_fkey foreign key (created_by) references auth.users (id),
    constraint lead_listing_id_fkey foreign key (listing_id) references listing (id),
    constraint lead_prospect_id_fkey foreign key (prospect_id) references prospect (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create index if not exists lead_prospect_id_idx on public.lead using btree (prospect_id) tablespace pg_default;

create index if not exists lead_listing_id_idx on public.lead using btree (listing_id) tablespace pg_default;

create index if not exists lead_created_by_idx on public.lead using btree (created_by) tablespace pg_default;

create index if not exists lead_deleted_at_idx on public.lead using btree (deleted_at) tablespace pg_default;

create trigger generate_reference_code_for_lead before insert on lead for each row
execute function generate_reference_code_for_lead ();



select * from lead is going to use a sequence scan because you are asking for everything, there is no point in using an index scan. 2) This is something you need to bring up with Supabase tech support as it most likely something on their end. In other words this is not the Postgres community version and we don't have access to whatever magic goes on behind the scenes at Supabase.


Planning is pretty bad, but on the other hand, what do you expect from a micro-machine with just a few MB's of memory?

@AdrianKlaver yes, aware of the fact it'll use a sequence scan. My point is that it shouldn't take 38s to plan that.

@Charlieface I did - it's the second code block.

@FrankHeikens it handles everything else we have just fine. Every other trivial query plans in milliseconds. It's literally just this table.

Run an analyze on this table and check the number of statistics for this table. (you can set this per table)

Exactly, which is why I suggested you contact Supabase tech support. It is their 'managed' solution, which means there are behind the scenes operations going on that only they can access.

I assume that at least one of your catalog tables must be bloated out of shape.  If you have millions of tables or schemas or users or some other object, that is a likely explanation.
If your object counts are moderate, you should use the pgstattuple() function from the extension with the same name to determine which of your catalog tables is bloated:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgstattuple;

SELECT t.oid::regclass,
       s.free_space
FROM pg_class AS t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL pgstattuple(t.oid) AS s
WHERE t.relkind = 'r'
  AND t.relnamespace = 11
  AND pg_relation_size(t.oid) > 81920
ORDER BY 2 DESC;

If you have a catalog table with tons of free space, use VACUUM (FULL) tablename to reorganize it.
It is also worth looking at bloated catalog indexes:
SELECT t.oid::regclass,
       100 - s.avg_leaf_density AS bloat_percent,
       pg_relation_size(t.oid) AS index_size
FROM pg_class AS t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL pgstatindex(t.oid) AS s
WHERE t.relkind = 'i'
  AND t.relnamespace = 11
  AND pg_relation_size(t.oid) > 81920
ORDER BY 2 DESC;

Indexes that are very bloated can be rebuilt with REINDEX INDEX indexname.
Without pgstattuple you cannot get an exact diagnosis. But you can look at the size of the system objects — anything that is large is a potential culprit:
SELECT oid::regclass,
       pg_relation_size(oid) AS object_size,
       CASE relkind
          WHEN 'r' THEN 'table'
          WHEN 'i' THEN 'index'
       END AS object_type
FROM pg_class
WHERE relnamespace = 11
  AND relkind IN ('r', 'i');


Is there a way to achieve this without pgstattuple? Supabase doesn't provide superuser credentials to hosted Postgres users, so I can't enable the extension as far as I can tell.
